# Overlay barplot with 2 y Axis

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I want a barplot that Overlays with 2 variables (2 y axis).

This is my plot

[image]

And this is what im looking for.

[image]

Here is all the data.

What I used to make the plot.

```
ylim3 <- max(mesbar) + 2000
mesbar <- c(total_septiembre, total_octubre)
barplot(mesbar, main = "Month income",
        ylim = c(0,ylim3))
grid()

> mesbar
[1]  1260 12710
```

And i want to overlapp it with this data (days worked)

```
> dias_trabajados_sep
[1] 2
> dias_trabajados_oct
[1] 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done. However, keep in mind that you are playing with the axis `ylims` and that viewers could say that it is misleading. The trick is to add `par(new = TRUE)` and a new `barplot`. I chose to add the blue color trough `rgb` as it allows transparency trough its `alpha` argument. This will be useful when the gray bars will be shorter than the blue bars.

```
mesbar <-c(1260,12710)
dias <- c(2,22)
ylim3 <- max(mesbar) + 2000
#mesbar <- c(total_septiembre, total_octubre)
barplot(mesbar, main = "Month income",
        ylim = c(0,ylim3))
grid()
par(new = TRUE)
barplot(dias, main = "Month income", col=rgb(0,0,1, alpha=.5),xaxt = "n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="", ylim=c(0,30))
axis(side=4)
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot

Comment: Really appreciate your help and time